# Pig order preservation across RANK and in general

Tags: sorting, apache-pig

In the following code:

```
dsBodyStartStopSort = 
order dsBodyStartStop 
   by terminal_id, point_date_stamp, point_time_stamp, event_code
;

dsBodyStartStopRank = 
rank dsBodyStartStopSort
;

store dsBodyStartStopSort
 into 'xStartStopSort.csv'
using PigStorage(';')
;
```

I know that if I *don't* do that RANK in the middle, the sort order will make it to the STORE command.  And that is guaranteed by Pig.

And it appears from the testing I've done that doing RANK does *not* mess up the sort order--but is that *guaranteed*?  I don't want to just be running on luck.

More generally, what is Pig's rule for preserving sort once it's done?  Is it until some reduce event occurs?  Will it work across FILTER?  Certainly not GROUP?  Just wondering if there is a well defined set of rules on when and how Pig guarantees or does not guarantee order.

To summarize: 1) Is order preserved across RANK?  2) How is order preserved generally?

Comment: Further runs indicate that DISTINCT will create order.  I have a JOIN that I know breaks order, but if I do a DISTINCT, the output is ordered.  but again, I'm trying to find documentation that guarantees this order will always be there.

Answer (score 0):

The best piece of documentation I found on the topic:

> Bags are disordered unless you explicitly apply a nested ORDER BY
>   operation as demonstrated below. A nested FOREACH will preserve
>   ordering, letting you order by one combination of fields then project
>   out just the values you'd like to concatenate.

From looking at unofficial examples and comments, I conclude the following:

- If you do an order right before a rank, it should preserve the order. Personally I prefer to just use `RANK xxx BY a,b,c;` and only use ORDER afterwards if it is really needed.
- If you do an order right before a LIMIT, it should feed LIMIT with the top lines. However the output would be sorted rather than in the original order.

Comment: Didn't find anything on whether order persists through a FILTER. Consider adding a RANK before the filter, and then order by the RANK later on (or you can ORDER twice, I don't think it will impact performance).